# How do I determine the date of a file, prior to uploading (with php)?

Tags: php

When I upload a file with PHP, there is the file creation date.  How do I grab the date of the original file?  I want to store both the upload date AND the date of the original file that the user is uploading.

Comment: Anything you have tried so far?

Comment: if you want to know the date of images, you can try to read the exif data.

Answer (score 1):

Use [filectime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filectime.php) this will return the creation date in windows. in Unix it will give you the last modification data because there is no creation time in Unix.

Use [touch](http://php.net/manual/en/function.touch.php) for changing the modification time of file.

Comment: i did "echo date("Y-m-d", filectime($_FILES['imagefile']['tmp_name'])) but the echoed date is Today not the original date of the uploaded file.